# Jquery mobile tap on element to remove it

Tags: jquery, tap

I have a function that appends some html on the fly to a container div. I want to be able to tap on this created html and make it go away, but cant seem to get it to work.

So for example if i have this function created from a tap on another element:

```
function functionName(e){
    $('<div />').attr({id: 'someid '}).text(' Text Text Text').appendTo('.container');
 }
```

I want to be able to then remove it like this:

```
$('someid').tap(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    }
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added the `#` to the selector to add the touch event to the `someid` element, as well as your ending `);`...

```
$('#someid').tap(function(){ ... });
```

You might also need to use something like the `.live()` function to 'on-the-fly' add the tap event handler to any elements that are added dynamically to the page's content. Something like:

```
$('#someid').live('tap', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

It should be OK if you use click() method

```
$('#someid').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

There's no problem with Android browser.

Comment: This does not work on iPad. Use the $('#someid').tap(function(){...}); approach